# Visual feedback when clicking on a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

I need to add visual feedback when a user click my frame. I followed some suggestions from similar questions but I can't get it work and I don't know why it isn't working. Here what I have done so far:

rectangle_visual_feedback.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"   android:drawable="@drawable/rectangle_visual_feedback" />
</selector>
```

rectangle_visual_feedback_selector.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#40808080"/>
<padding android:bottom="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp"></padding>
</shape>
```

fragment.xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout_mainwrap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_visual_feedback_selector"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_image"
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/thehotel_b" />

                <com.hotelstayapp.android.custom.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/customtextview_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code inside the fragment I use to call the RelativeLayout :

```
RelativeLayout relativelayout_mainwrap = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_mainwrap);
RelativeLayout relativelayout_mainwrap.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + Theme.BackColorOpacity + Theme.BackColor));
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: You've already given it a background in XML using `android:background`. Why are you then setting another background color in java?

Comment: Try to remove android:clickable="true" from parent layout

Answer (score 0):

For visual feedback you can create following drawable,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/navigation_icon_default" />
</selector>
```

and set this drawable to your relative layout's background.